# XBMC thumbnail scan?

Tags: kodi

Is there a feature or add-on in XBMC so that I can scan/fast-forward through a movie using thumbnails at ~1 minute intervals, like the PS3 has?

Comment: I use OpenELEC which bundles XBMC, and I have not found a way to change the preview thumbnails... :/

Answer (score 1):

I do not know of a way to scan through like that. If you want to jump through at one minute intervals, though, you would change your advancedsettings.xml file.

Inside the  tags (adjust the values accordingly):

```
<usetimeseeking>true</usetimeseeking>  <!-- Whether to use time based or percentage based seeking. -->
<timeseekforward>30</timeseekforward>  <!-- Time to seek forward in seconds when doing a short seek.  Defaults to 30. -->
<timeseekbackward>-10</timeseekbackward>  <!-- Time to seek backward in seconds when doing a short seek.  Defaults to -30. -->
<timeseekforwardbig>300</timeseekforwardbig>  <!-- Time to seek forward in seconds when doing a long seek.  Defaults to 600 (10 minutes). -->
<timeseekbackwardbig>-300</timeseekbackwardbig>  <!-- Time to seek backward in seconds when doing a long seek.  Defaults to -600 (10 minutes). -->
```

Comment: That's a shame. Even YouTube has thumbnail previews now.